# Django - подключение к базе по требованию

Tags: mysql, django, sqlite

Задача такова: у проекта есть 1 база, но только в определенной функции которая исполняется только на определенной странице необходимо подключение к сторонней базе данных.

То есть я могу добавить базу setting.py и все будет работать, но это будет влиять на производительность - при каждом запросе будет тратиться время на подключение к базе которая не будет использоваться.

Вот собственно и вопрос: как это сделать?